# How can I access an Ember input as a jQuery element?

Tags: ember.js

I have a simple form in Ember which submits to a server and returns a response. On a failed response, I want to re-focus on the input field. Is there a way to access the field in my controller using the value binding?

Here's my jsbin as an example:

http://jsbin.com/umodir/1/edit

Comment: I think the more minimalist way would be put a id attribute in input, and then call $("#somid").focus() in submit. But this is not the ember way ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/efatut/2/edit

Your server should return something that sets a property on your controller that you can observe. I made it pretty simple and called it "error".

```
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  error: false,
  submit: function() {
    alert('I want to set a focus on the email input field now...');
    this.set('error', true);
  }  
});

App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.Extend({
  focusEmail: function() {
    if (this.get('controller.error')) {
      this.$('input[type=text]').focus();
    }
  }.observes('controller.error')
});
```

If you wanted to get really fancy you could use an Ember.Component like `{{eb-input focuson="error"}}` that would automatically focus when the controller's "error" property changed.

Comment: This seems like a lot of extra code just to access the element. Is it best practice in Ember to only access elements via the views? Seems like there should be a much simpler way.