# Ember focus input on failed login?

Tags: ember.js

Before starting this question I found something similar to what I am looking for: [How can I access an Ember input as a jQuery element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17726286/how-can-i-access-an-ember-input-as-a-jquery-element)

The problem with that approach is `focusEmail()` method in the `View` will only get called the first time, when Controller's `error` property changes from false to true. If I submit the form again, the `error` is still true, so in a sense it hasn't changed, and thus View's `focusEmail()` is not fired.

What can I do here to focus an input element all the time, not just the first time when `error` changes from **false** to **true**?

#### My code

```
// login_view.js
var LoginView = Ember.View.extend({
  focusPassword: function() {
    if (this.get('controller.error')) {
      this.$('#password').focus();
    }
  }.observes('controller.error')
});

// login_controller.js
var LoginController = Ember.Controller.extend(Ember.SimpleAuth.LoginControllerMixin, {
  error: false,
  actions: {
    loginFailed: function(xhr) {
      this.set('error', true);
      this.set('errorMessage', xhr.responseText);
    }
  }
});
```

**Note:** The `loginFailed` is fired whenever non-**200** response is sent from the server. (I am using ember-simple-auth library)

**UPDATE**: I was able to get it working using `submit` method in LoginView. In addition to what I have above:

```
  submit: function() {
    this.get('controller').send('error', false);
  },
```

And then in controller:

```
error: function(value) {
  this.set('error', value);
}
```

*If someone has a better approach, simpler, and easier, post it below and and I will accept it as the answer.*

Comment: you should probably clear the errors on resubmit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to explicitly mark the error property as changed, with: notifyPropertyChange?
http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Object.html#method_notifyPropertyChange

Personally, I like your last solution more and if I had to implement it, I would have done the same thing.